# Polyline changes into polygon in google map drawing tool

Tags: google-maps, google

I have been using google map provided tools where it can draw the polygon and polyline accordingly. I will first click on the polyline icon and start plotting and suddenly when I double click it turn to be polygon and I notice icon which I clicked earlier have been not in selected mode now. Below is my codes where I do the calling when I do the overlay completed. So where could be my error ?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
     var newShape = e.overlay;
            newShape.type = e.type;
     if(e.type.toString()=="polygon"){
        //customised info window
     }
     else if(e.type.toString()=="polyline")
     {
       //customised info window
     }
     else if(e.type.toString()=="marker")
     {
      //customised info window
     }
 });
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
```